# Which of the following sentences is correct

Tags: sentence

Which one of these sentences is correct:
1) No regular classes will be there for Sunday School during June.
2) Regular classes will not be there for Sunday School during June.

Comment: Please never just ask “Which is correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences have correct syntax, but both are missing the verb *held* and the prepostional phrase should be removed in each:

1. No regular Sunday School classes will be held  there during June.
2. Regular Sunday School classes will not be held there during June.

Answer (score 1):

Although neither sentence is syntactically incorrect, neither is what would normally be written. Instead, you would likely write this as:

> There will be no regular Sunday School classes in June.

On the other hand, if you mean to imply the classes will take place, but somewhere else, you would want to write something like:

> In June, no regular Sunday School classes will be held there.